# gradle, idea plugin and multi-project setup

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to setup a multi-module gradle project with idea support. It works until I'm adding project-wide gradle.properties to the mix. Here's an example:

gradle.properties:

```
javaVersion = 1.8
```

gradle.settings:

```
include 'module_a'
```

build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  idea {
    project {
      jdkName = javaVersion
    }
  }
}
```

module_a is an empty sub-folder.

`gradle idea` fails with this:

```
Build file 'project/build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
> Cannot set property 'jdkName' on null object
```

What could be the reason?

Question 2: can a sub-project make modifications to the global `idea` task, for instance

```
idea.module.generatedSourceDirs += file('srm/main/java.generated')
```

Will it only affect `module_a` if placed in `module_a/build.gradle` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set "jdkName" on every subproject, it only should set on the root project like this:

```
idea {
  project {
    jdkName = "1.8"
    languageLevel = "1.8"
  }
  module {
    name = "My root project name"
  }
}
```

On the sub projects you can config other things like

```
idea.module.testSourceDirs = idea.module.testSourceDirs+idea.module.sourceDirs
idea.module.sourceDirs = [] as Set
```